# Autowired with Spring BOOT and Mockito in JUnit Test cases without having any context configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am looking for solution where I can use Autowired annotation on some beans which get injected while I Inject Mocks for the main bean.
    I have some class A like this and I want to use Autowired D instead of mocked D in Test class. I am using spring boot version 2.0 . Please let me know if someone knows any solution for this.

```
   @Repository
   Class A{

     B b;
     C c;
     D d;

     @Autowired
     public A(B b, C c, D d)
     {
           this.a =a;
           this.b = b;
           this.c = c;
      }

}
```

And I am trying to achieve this by Using Mockito as well some Autowired annotation for some dependency. I don't want to Mock D . This approach isn't working I want to know what I can do to make this working. If anyone has used Mockito along with Autowired annotation.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
Class ATest{

   @Autowired
   @InjectMocks
   A a;

   @Mock
   B b;

   @Mock
   C c;

   @Autowired
    D d;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the current status? What is your question?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: When I try to use solution as mentioned in Question: I get error for Autowiring A and D
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'A'

Comment: Are you trying do write unit test or integration test? Seems to me that you want integration test but you are trying to write unit test.

Comment: I am Trying to test A class but the D class is a external API That I am trying to inject

Comment: Why not mock that as well?

Comment: I want that to run test the api. Hence I am looking for some solution where I can use mocker with Autowired objects

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying do write unit test, you can use mockito to run which you are already using.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
Class ATest{

   @InjectMocks
   A a = new A();

   @Mock
   B b;

   @Mock
   C c;

   @Mock
    D d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution to my problem, If I user @Spy annotation instead of @Mock on object to Type D in test class it will invoke actual instead of Mock.